# How to align data in tabular environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, positioning, columns

After many hours of googling and testing a lots of packages, I succeded to make a table in a double column mode look like this:

[image]

using the following Code:

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[!b]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is the table's caption.}
\label{t:table1}
\vspace{-.7em}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.228\linewidth}p{0.228\linewidth}p{0.228\linewidth}p{0.228\linewidth}}
\toprule
\text{Parameters}\tnotex{tn:a}  & Calculated\tnotex{tn:b}   & Calculated\tnotex{tn:c}   & Calculated\tnotex{tn:d} \\ 
\midrule
A                               & 1234                      & 1234                      & 1234 \\
B                               & -123                      & -12                       & -12 \\
C                               & -123                      & -123                      & -123 \\ 
D                               & 123                       & 123                       & 123 \\
E                               & -123                      & -123                      & -123 \\
F                               & -123                      & 12                        & -123 \\ 
G                               & 123                       & 123                       & 123 \\
H                               & 1234                      & 1234                      & 1234 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] \label{tn:a} Parameters' Values reported in Ref a.
\item [b] \label{tn:b} Parameters' Values reported in Ref b.
\item [c] \label{tn:c} Parameters' Values reported in Ref c.
\item [d] \label{tn:d} Parameters' Values reported in Ref d.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

With only the packages existed in the code above (if possible) what do i have to change to get the table with the same spacing and data alignment as this one:

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `siunitx` and `tabular*`:

```
\documentclass[5p,times]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{multirow, graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{dblfloatfix}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage[referable]{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelfont=bf,labelsep=newline}
\captionsetup{labelsep=space,justification=justified,singlelinecheck=off}

\usepackage[colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\lipsum

\begin{table*}[!bp]
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{This is the table's caption.}
\label{t:table1}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  @{\extracolsep{\fill}}
  l
  S[table-format=-3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.0]
  @{}
}
\toprule
Parameters\tnotex{tn:a} & {Calculated\tnotex{tn:b}} &
   {Calculated\tnotex{tn:c}} & {Calculated\tnotex{tn:d}} \\ 
\midrule
A & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 \\
B & -123 &  -12 &  -12 \\
C & -123 & -123 & -123 \\ 
D &  123 &  123 &  123 \\
E & -123 & -123 & -123 \\
F & -123 &   12 & -123 \\ 
G &  123 &  123 &  123 \\
H & 1234 & 1234 & 1234 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [a] \label{tn:a} Parameters' Values reported in Ref a.
\item [b] \label{tn:b} Parameters' Values reported in Ref b.
\item [c] \label{tn:c} Parameters' Values reported in Ref c.
\item [d] \label{tn:d} Parameters' Values reported in Ref d.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table*}

\lipsum
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

A few points to note:

1. The headers for the `S` columns should be braced
2. The value for `table-format` should reflect the number of digits in the integral part and in the fractional part; here the numbers have at most four digits in the integral part, but a minus sign is wider than a digit, so `-3.0` fits the data

[image]

If you want to have padding at the sides of the table, change the preamble into

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{
  l
  @{\hspace{2\tabcolsep}\extracolsep{\fill}}
  S[table-format=-3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.0]
  S[table-format=-3.0]
}
```

[image]